# How do NEF networks differ from ANNs in applications?

Tags: neural-networks

As I've described [here](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/8141/whats-the-functional-difference-between-the-nef-and-normal-anns/8142#8142), the [Neural Engineering Framework](http://compneuro.uwaterloo.ca/research/nef.html) (NEF) has some functional similarities to Artificial Neural Networks (ANNs). Naturally, there is also an overlap in applications between NEF-based neural networks and ANNs. For example, [Spaun](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/338/6111/1202.full?ijkey=y5vph.jw5AgRQ&keytype=ref&siteid=sci), which was built using the NEF, was used to recognize digits from the MNIST data set. Anecdotally, I've also seen an NEF-based network used for gesture recognition.

At both of these tasks, the ANNs vastly surpassed the NEF-based networks. So what's the point on "taking-on" the ANNs on their own turf, aside from biological plausibility? What does a NEF-based network offer application-wise that can't be filled more adequately by an ANN?